# How to push files from Azure blob storage to GitHub?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-web-apps

I am in need to push the files from azure blob container folder to GitHub. I have a .sh script which works fine on my laptop. Now how can I run the same script in the azure cloud ?. The script itself need inotifywait (window) or fswatch (mac).

Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Logic App to automate that process, or download the files with Azure Storage Explorer and then manually push them

Here is an example bicep template iac to create that logic app

```
    param storageAccountName string
param storageContainerName string
param blobTriggerName string
param githubRepositoryOwner string
param githubRepositoryName string
param githubToken string
param githubFilePath string
param logicAppName string

resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties: {
    definition: {
      $schema: "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
      actions: {
        // Trigger when a blob is added or modified
        'When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)': {
          inputs: {
            host: {
              connection: {
                name: `@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']`
              }
            },
            method: 'get',
            path: `/datasets/default/triggers/onupdatedfile`,
            authentication: '@parameters('$authentication')['connectionId']'
          },
          metadata: {
            blobName: "@triggerOutputs()?['headers']['x-ms-file-path']",
            blobUri: "@triggerOutputs()?['headers']['x-ms-file-path']",
            lastModified: "@triggerOutputs()?['headers']['Last-Modified']",
            size: "@triggerOutputs()?['headers']['x-ms-blob-content-length']"
          },
          recurrence: {
            frequency: 'OnAdd'
          },
          splitOn: "@triggerOutputs()?['body']"
        },
        // List blobs
        'List_blobs': {
          inputs: {
            host: {
              connection: {
                name: `@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']`
              }
            },
            method: 'get',
            path: `/datasets/default/diagnostics',
            authentication: '@parameters('$authentication')['connectionId']'
          }
        },
        // For each blob, get content and create or update file in GitHub
        'For_each': {
          actions: {
            'Get_blob_content': {
              inputs: {
                host: {
                  connection: {
                    name: `@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']`
                  }
                },
                method: 'get',
                path: `/datasets/default/files/@{encodeURIComponent(item().name)}`,
                authentication: '@parameters('$authentication')['connectionId']'
              },
              metadata: {
                blobName: "@item().name",
                blobUri: "@item().name",
                contentSize: "@item().size",
                contentTypeId: 'binary'
              }
            },
            'Create_or_update_file': {
              inputs: {
                method: 'post',
                uri: "https://api.github.com/repos/@{githubRepositoryOwner}/@{githubRepositoryName}/contents/@{githubFilePath}/@{encodeURIComponent(item().name)}",
                headers: {
                  Authorization: "Bearer @{githubToken}"
                },
                body: {
                  message: "Add blob content to GitHub",
                  content: "@{base64(outputs('Get_blob_content')?['body'])}"
                }
              },
              runAfter: {
                'Get_blob_content': [
                  'Succeeded'
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          foreach: "@outputs('List_blobs')?['body']['value']"
        }
      },
      triggers: {
        manual: {
          type: 'manual'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

output logicAppResourceId string = logicApp.id
```